# Codeigniter: Produce Array instead of Object in Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I want Codeigniter produce array result in active record, just like  `mysql_fetch_array()` does in standard PHP.

Let's just say, we have this table in our mysql database, called students.

```
+-----+------+
| id  | name |
+-----+------+
|  1  | Elto |
|  2  | John |
+------------+
```

This is the conditions. 
I generate the query in separated way. It's Just like :

```
$this->db->select('id, name');
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$q = $this->db->get('students');
$r = $q->result();
```

`$r` will produce:

```
[0] (name => 'Elto')
[1] (name => 'John')
```

Instead of that, I want the query produce something like this:

```
[0][0] => 'Elto'
[1][0] => 'John'
```

I don't know if this can be done. If anyone wants to help this problem, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `result_array()` instead of `result()`:

```
$this->db->select('id, name');
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$q = $this->db->get('students');
$r = $q->result_array();
```

`result()` will return you rows in Object format.

`result_array()` will return you rows into array format.

Please explore **[CodeIgniter Generating Query Results](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)**

Comment: Thank you for your response. This method works well, but does not produce what I wanted. `result_array()` will generate an _associative array_ while **indexed array** is what I need. But it can be tricked with a `php` function: `array_values()`. But I do not know if there are any performance issues that may occur.

Comment: How counter intuitive for this answer to not provide the desired result, yet has been accepted.  How confusing for researchers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$r = $q->result_array();
```

or you can use

```
$r = $q->row_array();
```

To retrive only one item.

Check offical documentation for more information:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**Codeigniter 4:**

```
$r = $q->getResultArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that not only the first level contains indexed arrays, but also that each row contains indexed elements, apply a numeric alias to the `name` column in your SELECT statement and then use `result_array()` or `getResultArray()` (depending on your CI version).

Depending on your database driver, the alias quoting character may vary.  Tested on my application running firebird, double quoting the numeric alias rendered properly.

```
return $this->db
            ->select('name AS "0"')
            ->order_by('name', 'ASC')
            ->get('students')
            ->result_array();
```

Will return an indexed array of single-element, indexed arrays.

```
[
    [0 => 'Elto'],
    [0 => 'John'],
]
```